# How should I implement a tf.keras.Metric that computes on the whole prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The `tf.keras.Metric` interface provides a useful tool for implementing additive metrics such as loss/accuracy. The interface is designed to update on a batch when `update_state(self, y_pred, y_true)` is called and the result should be returned at `result(self)`. However when implementing some metrics like FID, Inception Score, Expected Calibration Error, we have to look at the whole set of the predictions instead of iterative views of individual samples. How am I supposed to implement such custom metrics in Tensorflow? Should I use another API?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you question;

```
class BinaryTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

  def __init__(self, name='binary_true_positives', **kwargs):
    super(BinaryTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.bool)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.bool)

    values = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, True), tf.equal(y_pred, True))
    values = tf.cast(values, self.dtype)
    if sample_weight is not None:
      sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, self.dtype)
      sample_weight = tf.broadcast_to(sample_weight, values.shape)
      values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
    self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

  def result(self):
    return self.true_positives
```

[example from [tf2 docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric)]
in the `update_state()` method we implements the metrics calculation function. In essence, `update_state()` returns a single for whole mini-batch. So, mini-batch evaluation is possible in tf2. But, to support batch evaluation metrics you have to update whole your input pipeline as well.

Comment: I can obviously do this with a custom training loop but I wonder how we can do this within `model.fit` (or `evaluate`). I understand that you are suggesting that this is impossible using `Metric`, but what about other APIs? Something like `Callback` could do the job :) Any ideas on how to implement this with something else?

Comment: you can add custom metrics in the parameter of `metrics` in the `model.fit` function, until the input of the `update_state()` and `x` and `y` in the `model.fit`.